# EXCEL, Find a specific text&number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

There are three sheets.
Sheet2 and Sheet3 have specific SKUs such as ABC123, BCD234, CDE345... If the specific SKU is in sheet2, I would like to say the SKU is from "USA", and if the SKU is in sheet3, it is from "China"
On Sheet1, I would like to find BCD234 and carry where it is from.

Thank you

Comment: You should play around with `VLOOKUP` and `IFERROR` keywords. When `VLOOKUP` cannot find a value in the target cells, it would throw a **#N/A** error. If you can catch this error with `IFERROR`, you would be able to find which sheet **does not** contain your value. If you may share the sample file, I would try to write the exact formula.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you need for labeling the SKUs as China or USA assuming the SKUs are in column A on all sheets.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet3!A:A,0)),"SKU Missing","China"),"USA")
```

It's not clear to me if you want another formula for identifying which sheet the SKU came from.  And why that particular SKU?  Is is because it starts with BCD?  If you can explain that further I can update this answer to include your additional request.